# How to convert python(.py) file to unreadable code format

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have written python code and saved as program.py file.Now When i open "program.py" file it should be unreadable format.

Can anyone suggest me how to fix this issue.

Comment: Maybe this link can help you out: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/261638/how-do-i-protect-python-code)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can creat `pyc` file with `compileall`:

Put your python files in a folder and run the command in this folder:([Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22779209/6900838))

```
python -m compileall .
```

This command will produce a `pyc` file in `__pycache__` folder. You can use this file like other python files:([Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12987857/6900838))

```
python myfile.pyc
```

Comment: You can still read the .pyc file and some import info is seen as well using Linux "cat" command

Comment: @manjesh23 Yes, strings and docstring are also readable, but its priority is not hiding the code. `pyc` files contain the bytecode to speed up the process for the next run. However, it is not readable in general.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do that is by compiling the source code using the `py_compile` module:

```
python -m py_compile my-py-source.py
```

The compiled source code will be in `_pycache/my-py-source.pyc` (relative to your current directory). And the code will still run normally when you run `python my-py-source.pyc`.