# How to make code unreadable but executbale?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows

I made my app using python(PyQt5). I converted py to exe using pyinstaller but after converting it looped at splash screen(My app has splash screen and main screen.). So,I decided to stay it as py file but can I make it unreadable for user? I mean only my app can execute it and normal users couldn't able to see source code?

*Note:This program is only for Windows.*

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/47636712/3890632

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47636712/how-to-convert-python-py-file-to-unreadable-code-format?noredirect=1&lq=1 should do it, though it doesn't mention .exe conversion

Answer (score 0):

`pyinstaller` is the way to go. It does work with libraries you use. It seems you have some underlying problems though.

Another alternative is `py2exe`.

Did you try some reasearch into `pyinstaller` options? Some suggest using `--onefile` option of `pyinstaller`.

Comment: I tried it. Already tried all combinations of pyinstaller. Btw, I would ask how can I compress all files of program(I mean folders, db, other files) into one exe with not changing the paths? I mean it launches UI file from data/ui folder and I coded it as ./data/UI in main.py . After converting all this folders to an exe file can it work correctly without errors?

Comment: Make sure your program works in `pyinstaller`'s `one-folder` mode first. You can see how it works here: https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/operating-mode.html